# Is there any way to create Customer in stripe

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, strip

I am trying to implement a Stripe Payment Gateway in my application. I have successfully generate token. But Now i want add or create new customer in my subscription plan, which is already describe on `Stripe Dashboard`. There is Bit of code for creating token

```
STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: stripCard, completion: { (token, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            let errorDes = error! as NSError
            self.handleError(error: errorDes.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        self.postStripeToken(token: token!)
    })
```

After that i want to create a customer but i am not able to find any swift `Stripe class`.
What is the procedure to create an `customer`.

`This is the function where i am getting token`

```
func postStripeToken(token: STPToken) {
    print("STPToken=\(token)")
}
```

**UPDATED**
`I am sending this token to the api call and make subscription or payment from the api call`
So apple has reject my application with the feedback.

I am using Api Call for that but `Itune Store Has reject my application` with the message `We noticed that your app provides access to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, which does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, your app allows users to obtain a membership inside the app without using In App Purchase.

> Itune Store Has reject my application`with the message`We noticed that your app provides access to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, which does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, your app allows users to obtain a membership inside the app without using In App Purchase.

Comment: If I am correct, you have to do an API call and in the API you create the new stripe user.

Comment: @Mar-k it means `we can not create customer on the iPhone without calling and api call`. But when i was implementing on the`Android` their we can create an Customer without calling an API. But Why we can not do same thing in the `Swift`

Comment: I only did something with stripe once and back then the account was created in the backend... I hope someone else has a good solution for you. Good luck!

Comment: @Mar-k I am using Api Call for that but `Itune Store Has reject my application` with the message `We noticed that your app provides access to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the app, which does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, your app allows users to obtain a membership inside the app without using In App Purchase.`